# How to convert a JS hash table into an array with a specific order?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I've got:

```
var productsSelected = {
  mouse: "Logitech 232",
  display: "27-inch LCD",
  memory: "8GB",
  videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS",
  extendedWarranty: "",
  extraBattery: "",
  antivirus: "",
  cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz"
}
```

I would like to convert this into an array with a certain order:

```
var productsSelectedArray = [
  {cpu: "Core i7 2.4GHz"},
  {memory: "8GB"},
  {videoCard: "nVidia 6500-GTS"},
  {display: "27-inch LCD"},
  {extraBattery: ""},
  {antivirus: ""},
  {mouse: "Logitech 232"},
  {extendedWarranty: ""}
]
```

I can give this function an array that defines the order I want:

```
var desiredOrder = [
  "cpu",
  "memory",
  "videoCard",
  "display",
  "extraBattery",
  "antivirus",
  "mouse",
  "extendedWarranty"
]
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to write this function. I have UnderscoreJS installed as well.

I'm thinking that I would start with a function that takes the `desiredOrder` array and `productsSelected` hash as arguments and it would declare `productsSelectedArray` as an empty array.

```
var convertHashToArray = function(hashTable, desiredOrderArray){
   ...
}
```

It would loop through `desiredOrder` and for each value it would do a lookup of that value in the `productsSelected` hash. It would then push a hash with key `desiredOrder[i]` and value `result of lookup in productsSelected` to the array, right?

**EDIT**

Thanks guys for all the answers! I'm glad I asked... I don't believe I would have come up with such short solutions.

Comment: I want to know, for one, if there's a much easier way to do it. Maybe using Underscore? I'd hate to code all this out and then later discover I could have done it in like one line, haha.

Comment: Even without the helper methods from underscore (eg, `_.map`) its still only like 5 lines or so in vanilla javascript (see my answer)

Comment: I think you can use javascript map for this. I got something working, added as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would loop through desiredOrder and for each value it would do a lookup of that value in the productsSelected hash. It would then push a hash with key desiredOrder[i] and value result of lookup in productsSelected to the array, right?

Yes, that's just how to do it. With underscore:

```
function convertHashToArray(hashTable, desiredOrderArray){
     return _.map(desiredOrderArray, function(key) {
         return _.object([[key, hashTable[key]]]);
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. There is no way that I would have come up with this particular underscore solution.

Comment: It's just the shortest one I could come up with. The `map` is fairly trivial, but I don't like `_.object` - I wish there was a better way. Maybe the native callback that @Mritunjay has used would be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertHashToArray(productsSelected, desiredOrder) {
    var productsSelectedArray = [];

    desiredOrder.forEach(function(item){
        var obj = {};
        obj[item] = productsSelected[item];
        productsSelectedArray.push(obj);   
    })
}
```

Comment: -1 this only gives you an array of values. OP wanted an array of (single property) objects

Comment: Also [don't use `for in` on arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
function toOrderedList(input, order){
    var result = [];
    for(var i=0;i<order.length;i++){
        var item = {};
        item[order[i]] = input[order[i]];
        result.push(item);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And call it like:

```
var newArray = toOrderedList(productsSelected,desiredOrder);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3jvFq/

Answer (score 0):

This should work in simple way

```
var orderedProducts = desiredOrder.map(function (elem) {
    var obj = {};
    obj[elem] = productsSelected[elem];
    return obj; 
});
```

I've variables given in question.